# Understanding the role of num_workers in Pytorch's Dataloader

Tags: pytorch

In PyTorch's Dataloader suppose:

I) Batch size=8 and num_workers=8

II) Batch size=1 and num_workers=8

III) Batch size=1 and num_workers=1

with exact same `get_item()` function.

So,

- in case I) will 1 worker be assigned for each batch and in case II) only 1 worker will be used and 7 idle.
- Or is it that even in case II) all 8 workers will be used for that loading that single batch
- Or is it that 1 worker will be used to load batch for each iteration. I mean say I am on iteration x, and irrespective of batch size batches for future iterations will be pre-loaded as I am using multiple workers?

Finally, will speed of training my CNN be greater in Case II or case III, or will it be same?

Answer (score 3):

Every worker process is always responsible for loading a whole batch, so the batch size and number of workers are not really related.

> in case I) will 1 worker be assigned for each batch and in case II) only 1 worker will be used and 7 idle.

All 8 workers will load batches and deliver them whenever required. So as soon as they are done loading their number of batches (defined by `prefetch_factor`) they just queue up to deliver the data.

> Or is it that even in case II) all 8 workers will be used for that loading that single batch

No, there is always just one worker responsible per batch.

> Or is it that 1 worker will be used to load batch for each iteration. I mean say I am on iteration x, and irrespective of batch size batches for future iterations will be pre-loaded as I am using multiple workers?

Every batch is loaded by *one* worker, so if you only load one batch per iteration, only one worker is in taht iteration.